# How to add a class to a xaml page

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

this is windows phone 8 app.

I have a class like this in namespace `MyApp.Converters`:

```
public class CustomConverter : IValueConverter
{
}
```

I want to add this to a XAML page, but I don't know how?!

I did this:

```
xmlns:MyApp.Converters="clr-namespace:MyApp.Converters"
```

and

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <MyApp.Converters:CustomConverter x:Key="customConverter"/>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

I get this error:

> Length cannot be less than zero

How to add a class to a XAML page? thanks

Comment: I guess there is a problem in the implementation or using of the class. Show us more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be an issue when you put a dot in the prefix name. If you remove it then it should work:

```
xmlns:MyAppConverters="clr-namespace:MyApp.Converters"
```

and

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <MyAppConverters:CustomConverter x:Key="customConverter"/>    
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

Comment: It's not working if the CustomConverter is a NavigationPage. It complains that NavigationPage doesn't get a Page. But it works if the NavigationPage code is directly in the parent file instead of in a different one.

Answer (score 2):

we can have the following mapping to the namespace

```
    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage xmlns:c="clr-namespace:MyApp.Converters"> 

    <UserControl.Resources>

    <c:CustomConverter x:Key="myconverter">

    </c:CustomConverter> 

    </UserControl.Resources>
```

and you can bind the key as below wherever you need it
        `{Binding Converter={StaticResource myconverter}}`

also you can refer to the following link which may help you
    http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/Giving-alternate-color-to-each-row-of-ListBox-in-Windows-phone-7-2280.php